# How to get year component from a String in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nlp

I'm trying to do pattern matching with the input string. I'm able to get other keywords which are required for processing.

Currently I'm getting year component by comparing, if the input string has, "2019" or "1991", and so on. Sample code below:

```
let year = ["1975", "1976", "1977", ..... "2019"]

func getYear(inputString: String) -> String {
  for eachWord in inputString {
    if (year.contains(eachWord)) {
      return eachWord
    }
  }
  return ""
}
```

**Input 1:** "Get me the number goals Ronaldo scored in 2019." **Output Year 1:** "2019"

**Input 2:** "Who scored most runs in World Cup Cricket 1991 ." **Output Year 2:** "1991"

**Input 3:** "Who was Hockey world player of the year in 1975" **Output Year 3:** "1975"

**Question:** But how to get year component from string, in Swift without checking for hard-coded values in input string? Or what is the best possible way to get the year component from the Input String?

Comment: Use a regular expression to find 4 digit numbers then check if the number is within a range you would consider a valid year.

Answer (score 0):

Code for getting the year component from the Input String.

```
let string = "Get me the number goals Ronaldo scored in 2019."
let stringArray = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
for item in stringArray {
    if item.count == 4 {
        if let number = Int(item) {
            print("number: \(number)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the input string is - "There are 6734 books in our library." :)